# Use \textwidth in cm inside \pgfmathsetmacro

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths

How to set `\pgfmathsetmacro{\figurewidth}{\the\textwidth}` with `\the\textwidth` expressed in cm?

I tried with the `lengthconvert` package which works very well to print the text width in cm but it fails within `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

**Non-working MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lengthconvert}
\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}
    
    textwidth in pt:\the\textwidth
    
    textwidth in cm: \Convert[unit=cm]{\the\textwidth}
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\timefigurewidth}{\Convert[unit=cm]{\the\textwidth}}
    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can divide the length by `cm` to get its value in cm. Notice that `\pgfmathsetmacro` yields a macro, not a length.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lengthconvert}
\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}
    
    textwidth in pt:\the\textwidth
    
    textwidth in cm: \Convert[unit=cm]{\the\textwidth}
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\timefigurewidth}{scalar(\textwidth/1cm)}% scalar is not absolutely necessary but cleaner
    \edef\timefigurewidth{\timefigurewidth cm}%
    textwidth in cm computed by pgf: \timefigurewidth

\end{document}
```

[image]